# Storing variable value through jquery-dialog flow

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dialog

I am doing a dirty form check. While doing that, if the form value changes I show the user a prompt asking if he/she wants to proceed. If yes, I want to navigate to the url of clicked link. My problem is that I am not able to retain the url.

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        if(str != $("form").serialize()){
            $('#prompt').show();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

I am using the bootstrap dialog to show message that form has been changed. Now if the user still wants to leave page, how do I keep track of the url I need to forward.

```
<div class="modal-footer">  
            <a id="hide" class="btn">Stay on Page</a>
            <a id="navigate" class="btn" href="#">Leave Page</a>  
        </div>

$('#navigate').click(function () {
        console.log(url)
    });
```

I need a way to retain the value of url, when I close the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with with where `url` is defined. I made a quick js fiddle that shows two examples of it work and not working depending on where url is defined http://jsfiddle.net/zdgNS/4/.

This javascript should works as my examples shows:

```
(function() {
     var url;
    $('#link').click(function() {
        url = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        console.log(url);
    });
})();
```

If you want to read more about javascript variable scope, read this question: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Comment: What I am looking for is that when I select leave page, I should have access to the url variable.
Even if I can return back to the .click function, it would work for me.

Comment: Huh... I guess i don't quiet understand what you are going for. In the example I gave both `click` functions have access to the url variable. and whether the click function has access to the url variable has everything to do with where you define the url variable.